# Multiple foreign key validation

Tags: python, django, validation, foreign-keys

For example we use the polls app in the django tutorial
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial07/

We can modify the Choice model to prevent duplicate choice text by the following

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question,
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def clean(self):
        super(Choice, self).clean()
        choice_list = Choice.objects.filter(question=self.question)
        choice_list_text = [a.choice_text for a in choice_list if a.pk != self.pk]
        choice_list_text.append(self.choice_text)
        if len(set(choice_list_text)) != len(choice_list_text):
            raise ValidationError("You have duplicate entries")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

In the admin, the Choice model is inline with the Question form. This means that the validation will 100% work if the inline choice is edited one at a time. We can have a case as follows

```
Choice: A choice, Votes: 0
Choice: Another choice, Votes: 0
```

Switched

```
Choice: Another choice, Votes: 0
Choice: A choice, Votes: 0
```

This will raise the ValidationError when saved.

How do you code the validation if we want to allow such cases? If it is not possible is it possible to make other inline model entry not editable if one entry is edited in the admin form?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that what you are trying to do is possible without customizing a lot of django's out-of-the-box formset logic. Note also that making other inline entries non-editable would not help in your example because none of the two switched entries could be saved on their own either. One thing though:

Instead of overriding `clean` for validation, in your case, you should use `unique_together`:

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    # ...
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('question', 'choice_text'),)
```

This will enforce unique choices for each question at the db-level and does not depend on `clean` to be called.